# How to combine StackNavigator and TabNavigator in React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

first of all thank you for reading this question,
I'm newbie of using react native,
now in my case :

I have 4 screens that will show in the tab navigator :

- Home
- Profile
- Artikel
- Loker

and I want to add **non tab navigator** ( StackNavigator ) screen to this project for detail of some screen  :

- Profile Detail
- Artikel Detail
- Loker Detail

I was trying and when I register this screen , it will show in the tab navigator, I won't to show that detail screen in the tab navigator.

I'm really confuse right now, how to combine stacknavigator and tabnavigator ?

here's my code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';

//screen tab
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import Artikel from '../screens/Artikel';
import Alumni from '../screens/Alumni';
import Loker from '../screens/Loker';

//non screen tab
import Profile from '../screens/Profile';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME = 'Home';

export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {

  navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) , headerShown : false});

  return (

    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME} 
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#58CB70'
      }}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}

        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="ios-home" />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Artikel"
        component={Artikel}
        options={{
          title: 'Artikel',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="ios-paper" />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Loker"
        component={Loker}
        options={{
          title: 'Loker',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="ios-briefcase" />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Alumni"
        component={Alumni}
        options={{
          title: 'Alumni',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="ios-people" />,
        }}
      />

    </BottomTab.Navigator>

  );
}


function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  const routeName = route.state?.routes[route.state.index]?.name ?? INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME;

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Home':
      return 'How to get started';
    case 'Links':
      return 'Links to learn more';
  }
}
```

thank you before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const HomescreenNavigator = () =>{
    return(<Stack.Navigator>
               <Stack.Screen component={ProfileDetail}/>
               <Stack.Screen component={ArtikelDetail}/>
           <Stack.Navigator />)
```

```
<BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME} 
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeTintColor: '#58CB70'
          }}>
          <BottomTab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreenNavigator} />

        </BottomTab.Navigator>
```

Is this what you mean? You can just create a new Stack "helper" component which would contain your Stack, and then pass that Stack component to the BottomTab.

Comment: thank you so much it's work but  I need to change a bit , but it's works ! thank you , you are amazing

Comment: @KaretNasiPadang Yes sorry I didn't write the whole code, I just wanted you to understand the basic idea of how to do this.

Comment: @randomboiguyhere please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287020/how-to-use-stack-navigation-or-tab-bar-navigation-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm answering but here there's my code for that.
I'm using materialBottomTabs that is more customizable, but I think if the same as yours

```
function getHeaderTitle(route) {

  const routeName = route.state
    ? route.state.routes[route.state.index].name
    : route.params?.screen || 'The Home s App';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Favorites':
      return 'Favorites';
    case 'Info':
      return 'Info about the App';
  }
  return routeName;
}
```

just set the titles into the `switch`

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

```
const NavTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={FavoritesScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Fav',
          tabBarIcon: () => IconFav(),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Info"
        component={InfoScreen}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Info',
          tabBarIcon: () => IconInfo(),
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>


<NavigationContainer>
 <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={NavTab}
      options={({route}) => ({
        headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),    
      })}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Detail"
      component={ItemDetailScreen}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

To set the title of the Screen into the Stack simply add into the component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerTitle: 'Screen Title', // it can be a variable
    });
  }, []);
```